# gorilla websocket - chain of closeHandler

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

In gorilla websocket, `websocket.Conn` struct has a method `SetCloseHandler()`, which set close handler of the connection.
If the passed handler is `nil`, it uses a default handler.

I wan't to keep the default handler, but do something else before or after the default handler.

Aka. a handler chain, e.g. some method like:

- `prependCloseHandler(h)`
  which add a handler at beginning of handler chain.
- `appendCloseHandler(h)`
  which add a handler at end of handler chain.

Then each handler in the chain will be executed in order.

Is there anyway to do that, **without** coping the default handler as part of my new handler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The package does not provide a direct mechanism for prepending or appending a handler for a [close message](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#CloseMessage).  Use this function as a starter for your function:

```
closeHandler := conn.CloseHandler()
conn.SetCloseHandler(func(code int, text string) error {
    // Add your code here ...
    err := closeHandler(code, text)
    // ... or here.
    return err
})
```

Note that the close handler is called when a close message is received from the peer, not when the connection is closed. Most applications should be good with the default handler.

Comment: Upvoted for the `Note` part, but It's coping code, you can do better by backup current handler, then set a new handler which invoke the previous handler, without coping code. That way you can do it even multiple times, without a single copy. And, the actually result is like a chain (only that it's in a recursive way, not iteration way), to provide an iteration way, I guess need to change gorilla-websocket's source code.